# php maths with variables

Tags: php, math

I have the following php variables in my code:

```
$masonry_item_width;
$masonry_item_padding;
```

I am trying to create a value for a new variable by doing soe maths with these two. Here is what I've written:

```
$skizzar_double_width_size = eval(
   'return'.($masonry_item_width*2)+$masonry_item_padding.';'
);
```

However, this returns nothing when I echo out `$skizzar_double_width_size`

I've never done maths with php variables before, is there something i'm doing obviously wrong?

Comment: Please, for the love of god, don't use eval.

Comment: @Bulk more than happy to not...especially if you suggest another way

Comment: Yes, you're using eval to do basic math. `$foo = $bar + $baz` would work just as well. You do **NOT** need eval for what you're trying. Please forget that eval() exists. It is an evil function, and it should NEVER be used.

Answer (score 2):

Try simply with this:

```
$skizzar_double_width_size = $masonry_item_width*2 +$masonry_item_padding;
```

To echo it out to HTML just write:

```
echo $skizzar_double_width_size;
```

And yes, it's that simple! :)

Comment: I thought it was a simple as that, how can I echo this out in html?

Comment: @SamSkirrow Just do something like this: `<?= $skizzar_double_width_size ?>` or equals to that: `<?php echo skizzar_double_width_size; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `eval()` just use this:

```
echo $skizzar_double_width_size = $masonry_item_width * 2 + $masonry_item_padding;
```

BTW: `eval()` === `evil()`, i have never seen a situation where you need `eval()` it just makes you problems